# Is there any list of Java enabled mobile devices?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I would like to find a list of mobile devices in the world on which I can run J2ME applications.

Comment: Why would you need this? It would be a huge list. Pretty much all current phones can run J2ME applications.

Comment: My advice will be to create a list of devices which DO NOT support Java. It will be way shorter

Comment: @Joachim, there are almost 80% devices in this world supports java. 
@Sorantis, yes this could be sorter way but how do i identify list of devices which does not support java. This is as complex as above.

Any way i got my Android.

Comment: funny: Android doesn't support standard Java. It's programmed using the Java language, but it's not running a Java VM. Instead it converts Java classes to Dalvik code and runs that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp#devicematrix

> The Java ME technology Device Matrix has been replaced by a database included with the [Java ME SDK 3.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp), which lets you find technical specifications on mobile devices using the built-in WURFL database search engine. Over 8000 mobile device specifications are available from the Java ME SDK.

So, just go download the Java ME SDK 3.0 and you'll find the list.

The following site may also be useful; http://www.mobilade.com/ml/home

Comment: Thanks,

I got which i was visualizing. Thanks again and Thanks to open source.